# OrientDB: How to obtain an inline behavior from aggregate functions when doing UPDATE

Tags: sql-update, aggregate-functions, inline, orientdb

OrientDB has a very particular way of handling SQL aggregate functions. It treats them as aggregate when only one parameter is given, and as inline when more than one parameter are given (in contrast to relying on the given data type, and then allowing aggregates of aggregates).

So, let's say we want to draw a guest list for an event.

This won't work:

```
SELECT title, SET(in("Attending").name) FROM event
```

And instead one has to run:

```
SELECT title, SET(in("Attending").name, in("Attending").name) FROM event
```

or

```
SELECT title, SET(in("Attending").name) FROM event GROUP BY title
```

These are not great solutions, but depending on the case, one of the two always works.

This is not the case when running updates, though...

**What if we need to use inline an aggregate function that doesn't take multiple lists as parameters within a query that doesn't support group by?**

```
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size)
```

As logical as this query may seem, it doesn't work. It returns a cumulative sum on each line. None of the following works either:

```
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size) GROUP BY title
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size, in("Attending").family_size) 
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size, NULL)
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size, 0)
UPDATE event SET guest_count = sum(in("Attending").family_size, [0])
```

Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

> In case you need to use a function as inline when you've only one parameter, then add a second one like "null":

```
SELECT first( out('friends').name, null ) as firstFriend FROM Profiles
```

See: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Functions.html#inline-mode

Comment: That's one of my examples above, and I already said it doesn't work with SUM! I obviously have read that page before asking the question.

Comment: That is the official answer. Perhaps you've found a bug. Thanks for the downvote, you've discouraged me from offering you my help in the future.

Comment: Downvote is not mine. I appreciate your effort, but people are supposed to downvote a wrong answer, so that it is not taken as the right answer later on.